# Issue with .CSV being inaccessible due to it being used by another process - VB.NET Application

Tags: windows, vb.net, csv, file-sharing

We are having an issue with a .CSV file, it is being locked by another process on any shared folder location.

Before mid December this worked with no problem, but since then our guys keep getting this same error on the files. "The process cannot access the file "Filename.." because it is being used by another process" Once they are written into once and it appears that the shared file resource is keeping this file open, we have checked and we can see the close request coming through on the file server but it doesn't appear to be successfully closing said file.

Here is the code snippet which I have chopped down to get rid of the unnecessary information for our VB.Net application which creates and writes to the file in case it relates to it but it appears to be something with file sharing on Windows.

```
        Try
            Dim nowPathString As String = Now().ToString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss")
            Dim nowString As String = Now().ToString() ' 
            Dim csvFilePath As String = $\\webserver\ExcelTest\Test-{nowPathString}.csv 'Path to create or existing file
            Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFilePath, False)
            outFile.WriteLine("Warehouse, StockItemCode, AllocationQuantity, Reference, SecondReference, ActivityDate")
            outFile.WriteLine($"Main, SHE060, 1, 123456, 123456-1, {nowString}")
            outFile.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Any help or suggestions on this is greatly appreciated!

We thought this issue may be server related so we created a shared folder on our local C drive and the same issue occurred but if you save the file onto your local C drive normally it works.

The way to get around this being stored on our server is to go in and manually close the file down by using console root and the "Shared Folders" snap-in.

Comment: Not really helpful to your problem, but you should probably put the Streamwriter in a using statement, that way you don't to have to write `outFile.Close()` as it will do all the correct disposal of its resources and look clearer

Comment: @Cal-cium it might be related. If an exception occurs after opening before closing, then the file will remain open because the line `outFile.Close()` will not be run. Wrap in a `Using` or add a `Finally` to the `Try` where you close the file, which is basically the same thing.

Comment: So, my thought being as _we can see the close request coming through_ this is really an environmental issue.  There have been many windows updates of late that just plain make windows file sharing problematic.  I do agree that wrapping your code in a Using is a good idea, but since you can see the close request not sure it will help much

Comment: I will give this a go and let you all know how I get on!

Comment: This issue is resolved for us. It has been resolved since Tuesday afternoon and I know Microsoft released a new patch this day for security issues. I believe within this patch there was a resolution for our issue we were having. Many Thanks for your help on this guys.